# check_box_tag not changing value when attribute value is true or false

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, checkbox

I have a check_box_tag for a form that updates the User's Profile attribute of `:show_hometown`. When I submit the form to toggle the value of `:show_hometown` the value of the check box input is "1" regardless of the change in the attribute. Can someone help me figure out what I am doing wrong?

Here's my form:

```
<%= form_tag({:action => "edit_show_hometown_settings", :controller => "profiles"}, :html => {:multipart => true }) do %>
<%= check_box_tag :show_hometown, 0, 1 %>
<%= @user.profile.hometown %>
<% end %>
```

Here's the action in the controller from where I'm updating the attribute:

```
def edit_show_hometown_settings
  @profile = current_user.profile
  if @profile.show_hometown == true
    if @profile.update_attributes(:show_hometown => false)
      redirect_to settings_path
    else
      redirect_to settings_path, :notice => 'Oops, something went wrong. Please try again.'
    end
  elsif @profile.show_hometown == false
    if @profile.update_attributes(:show_hometown => true)
      redirect_to settings_path
    else
      redirect_to settings_path, :notice => 'Oops, something went wrong. Please try again.'
    end
  end
end
```

And lastly, the migration I used to create the `:show_hometown` attribute:

```
t.boolean :show_hometown, :default => true
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
@profile.show_hometown == false || @profile.show_hometown == "0"
```

The checkbox will return a "0" value, not false, and apparently ruby doesn't understand "0" as false always (my development platform understands "0" as false, but my production platform doesn't, and I don't know the reason; it's probably the ruby version).